# AWS ECS Error When Creating Capacity Provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I am trying to create a Capacity Provider via Golang AWS CDK:

```
cluster := awsecs.NewCluster(stack, jsii.String("ecsCluster"), &awsecs.ClusterProps{
    Vpc: vpc,
    EnableFargateCapacityProviders: newTrue(),
})

//Creating auto scaling group to attach to cluster
autoScalingGroup := autoscaling.NewAutoScalingGroup(stack, jsii.String("ASG"), &autoScalingGroupProps{
    vpc: vpc,
    instanceType: ec2.NewInstanceType(jsii.String("t2.micro")),
    machineImage: ecs.ecsOptimizedImage.amazonLinux2(),
    minCapacity: jsii.Number(0),
    maxCapacity: jsii.Number(100),
})

autoScalingGroup.scaleOnCpuUtilization(jsii.String("CpuScaling"), &cpuUtilizationScalingProps{
    targetUtilizationPercent: jsii.Number(90),
})


capacityProvider := ecs.NewAsgCapacityProvider(stack, jsii.String("myCapProvider"), &asgCapacityProviderProps{
    autoScalingGroup: autoScalingGroup,
})
cluster.addAsgCapacityProvider(capacityProvider)
```

When I run deploy to create all the AWS resources I am getting this error for the capacity provider:

```
3:39:39 PM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ECS::CapacityProvider
| myCapProvider/myCapProvider
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: CreateCapacityPro
vider error: The specified capacity provider name is invalid. Up to 255 charact
ers are allowed, including letters (upper and lowercase), numbers, underscores,
and hyphens. The name cannot be prefixed with "aws", "ecs", or "fargate". Speci
fy a valid name and try again. (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Cod
e: ClientException; Request ID: azz1be40-53q6-452c-n080-l9676s851o39; Proxy: nu
ll)" (RequestToken: f4z2s97k-9w42-5198-236b-bdbfcf1dac83, HandlerErrorCode: Inv
alidRequest)
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to stop this invalid name error from appearing?
I looked at the Go documentation at - https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/awsecs#NewAsgCapacityProvider but it is using the same format I am using. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could it be the name of the cluster that's invalid? Looks like it's prefixed with `ecs` (`ecsCluster`) - try changing it to something that's not prefixed with either `ecs`, `aws`, or `fargate`

Comment: @goto thanks for answering, I tried this but it still had the same error

Comment: Is there anything more that you're not showing here? What does you CFN template look like?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your stack name doesnt start with ecs, aws, or fargate.
This error was reported in cdk examples repo [issue](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/issues/628). It was fixed when stack name was changed.